# Problem while summing good answers on online quiz system

Tags: php, mysql, input, sum

I'm trying to build an online quiz system for a driving school.
They asked me to make available that questions and answers will be added on database. I did make it but the problem is that I'm having a hard time knowing if the answers are correct.

The code I'm using to generate the form is this:

```
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY question_id ASC");


                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                            echo ' 

                            <section>
                            <h1>'.$row['question'].'?</h4>
                                </br> <hr> </br>

                                <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-4 foto pb-2">
<img  src="" style="max-width:100%;height: auto;" >
</div>
   <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
   <div class="pergjigjet mb-2 pl-2 pr-2" style="padding-left: .5rem!important;padding-right: .5rem!important;margin-bottom: .5rem!important;">
   <div class="pergjigje">
   <label><input type="checkbox" name="q_'.$row['question_id'].'_a_1" value="1"> '.$row['answer1'].'.</label>
   </div>
   <div class="pergjigje">
   <label><input type="checkbox" name="q_'.$row['question_id'].'_a_2" value="1"> '.$row['answer2'].'.</label>
   </div>
   <div class="pergjigje"><label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="q_'.$row['question_id'].'_a_3" value="1"> '.$row['answere'].'.</label>
   </div>
   </div>
</div>
</section>
```

The quiz has total 30 questions and max 3 correct answers. 
If you don't select all the right answers it needs to be wrong. It means that you don't get points if you haven't selected the right answers for the question.

Array of the post data is this.

```
    array(4) {
  ["q_1_a_1"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["q_1_a_2"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["q_2_a_1"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["q_2_a_2"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

The table is this,

```
id, 
question_id, 
exam_id, 
question, 
answer1,  
answer2,
answer3,
CorrectAnswers,
QuestionPoints
```

I store the correct answers in this format

```
1,2
```

P.S the client asked me to use mysql, not mysqli or PDO

Comment: mysql_* based functions are deprecated and shouldn't be used. both mysqli and PDO work with mysql server.. either client or Maj misunderstands what they are.

Comment: *"P.S the client asked me to use mysql, not mysqli or PDO"* - I hope this is used in an INTRANET only, if they want you to not use the more recent and safer mysql apis which offer a prepared statement. INTRA or not, they should still be used. I also hope that your client understands what web / data security is about.

Comment: *P.S the client asked me to use mysql, not mysqli or PDO*: does the client have programming, or general IT knowledge?  From the fact he asked for that, looks like he knows just enough to be dangerous.  Your job here is to explain, teach and convince him not to enforce that.  Sometimes a demonstration is required, like the time I told a client his own password from a clear text FTP he did, thinking it was secure.

Comment: SO is for "professional and enthusiast programmers."  If you're being paid you're a professional programmer. A professional builder would refuse a request from a client to build a stairway from weak materials. In the same way a professional programmer should refuse a request to build internet-facing applications in a way that invites cybercreeps. That's why `mysql_*` APIs were retired. Seriously.

Comment: It could be that they use an old version of PHP and have not updated their code for newer version of PHP that runs mysqli_

Comment: @O.Jones I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but just because someone is hired to do a web job, doesn't make them professional. However, I do agree with what you're saying though, to "that" certain degree ;-) I knew someone who builds websites from using ready-made templates and follow the install instructions. When I asked that person if they knew how to debug those if and when something would "go South" as it were, they responded with a "no". Now if someone can't debug, then they're not really professional, IMHO. So, if they're getting paid, they can hire someone to help them with this.

Comment: Yeah I tried to explain but he wants that. I'm just doing my job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better if you used array-style names for the answer checkboxes, and put the answer numbers in the `value`, e.g.

```
   <label><input type="checkbox" name="q_'.$row['question_id'].'[]" value="1"> '.$row['answer1'].'.</label>
   </div>
   <div class="pergjigje">
   <label><input type="checkbox" name="q_'.$row['question_id'].'[]" value="2"> '.$row['answer2'].'.</label>
   </div>
   <div class="pergjigje">
   <label><input type="checkbox" name="q_'.$row['question_id'].'[]" value="3"> '.$row['answer3'].'.</label>
   </div>
```

Then when the form is submitted, `$_POST['q_1']` will be an array of all the selected answers. You can convert this to a string with `implode(",", $_POST['q_1'])`, and compare this string with the list of correct answers in the table.